# dibujo.draw is not a function

Tags: javascript

hla estoy aprendiendo javascript y en esta ocacion me tope con un problema q tal vez es algo muy básico pero como recién estoy aprendiendo a programar no doy con el error. En código que dejare mas abajo ocurre un  error cuando intento acceder a la propiedad draw, cuando estaba investigando los objectos en javascript recomendaba que en vez de q nuestro constructor creara  una funcion crecer para cada una de las instancias como en el siguiente codigo

```
    function Animal (edad) {
  this.edad = edad;
  this.crecer = function () {
    this.edad = this.edad + 1;
    return this.edad;
  }
}
```

por lo que si creamos un array con 1000 instancias de Animal se crearán 1000 funciones distintas (e independientes), algo que en términos de eficiencia es tremendamente indeseable.

por lo tanto recomendaba escribir de la siguiente manera

```
    function Animal (edad) {
  this.edad = edad;
}

Animal.prototype.crecer = function () {
  this.edad = this.edad + 1;
  return this.edad;
};
```

ahora en mi codigo (debare mas abajo) almaceno cada objecto en un array y al intentar interar en cada y usando el metodo draw me arroja el siguiente error 
***dibujo.draw is not a function***

no se en q estoy fallando si alguien tiene la respues porfa me explican

mi codigo

```
    let x, y, newX, newY, oldy, oldx;
let circlecontainer= [];


for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){

    let red = Math.random() * 250;
    let green = Math.random() * 250;
    let blue = Math.random() * 250;
    x = Math.random() * innerWidth;
    y = Math.random() * innerHeight;
    var circle = new Circle (x,y,red,green,blue);
    circlecontainer.push(circle);

}

for (let i = 0; i < circlecontainer.length; i++) {

    let dibujo =circlecontainer[i].draw();

}

function Circle (x,y,red,green,blue){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;

}




Circle.prototype.draw = function(){

    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fillStyle = `rgba(${this.red},${this.green},${this.blue}, 0.7)`;
    c.fill();
};
```

Comment: Todo tu codigo esta junto? Porque pasaria primero por el for y luego crearia lo demas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que modificas el prototipo de `Circle` añadiendo el método `draw` después de intentar utilizarlo.

Debes ejecutar la instrucción en la que extiendes el prototipo antes de utilizar el método:

```
Circle.prototype.draw = function(){

    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fillStyle = `rgba(${this.red},${this.green},${this.blue}, 0.7)`;
    c.fill();
};

for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){

    let red = Math.random() * 250;
    let green = Math.random() * 250;
....
```

Comment: woo gracias xD no puedo creer que fuera ese simple error :v q pena